# Using Guard::LiveReload with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard, livereload

Hi I'm trying to get Guard::LiveReload set up and am terribly confused as to how this works. I've installed Guard, Livereload, etc., followed the instructions here: https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload, and updated my Gemfile and Guardfile accordingly.

I have my rails server running on localhost:3000 and when I do a 'bundle exec guard' it looks like my Guard server is working properly as well:

```
13:45:29 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/kyle/01 WDI/99 Projects/09 Reddit for Resources/reddit-for-resources'
13:45:29 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect.
```

I then click on the chrome extension and see:

```
[1] guard(main)> 13:47:58 - INFO - Browser connected.
13:47:58 - INFO - Browser connected.
```

But -- that's it. When I make changes to my files and save, I don't see anything change on the browser without manually reloading.

Visiting the Guard server at localhost:35729 shows '404 Not Found'. Can't seem to find any more instructions that provide more detail -- can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue was due to Sublime Text 3 'atomic save' and Linux. Turning 'atomic save' off resolved the issue.

Specifically, add the following to your user perferences in ST3:
`"atomic_save": false` and it should work properly.

Spent a lot of time troubleshooting this issue so if anyone has any further questions feel free to reach out. As a general rule, run guard with --debug to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

was fixing this just a few days ago. Guard::Livereload works in conjunction with `rack-lifereload` you need to install this first https://github.com/johnbintz/rack-livereload (note there is middleware to tap in)

Guard just kicks the rack-lifereload when files are changed.

To make sure it works, open up the page's HTML and you should see some extra JS files that point to the life reload port

Comment: Thanks Nikolay -- have added rack-livereload, and see '<script type="text/javascript"> RACK_LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729; </script>' in my head -- but doesn't seem to be working just yet. Perhaps I'm still missing something -- I launch my rails server, launch guard, click the chrome extension ... is there anything else I need to be doing?

Comment: did you add the `livereload` section to your Guardfile? just in case here's mine https://gist.github.com/MadRabbit/8909565

Comment: Got it! Turns out it was a very specific Linux + Sublime Text 3 issue. The solution was to turn off 'atomic save' in ST3 user preferences ( "atomic_save": false). Full discussion here: https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/155